# R's lm() and predict.lm() are too slow. Looking for fast prediction using coefficients of regressions produced by lm.fit

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to fit several million models, then measure their performance in out of sample prediction (pick the lowest RMSE).

I originally used lapply() on several models with lm(), then would predict on out of sample observations from predict.lm() but it was far too slow.

I encountered on other threads that lm.fit() is faster, and it really is. But I'm now uncertain of the best way to use the coefficients for prediction.

I have also tried the speedglm package, but it hasn't been working for me.

Please see my code below.

```
#findcombo gets every possible combination of variables and places them in a 
list of character vectors
findcombo <- function(x){
  do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) combn(x, i, FUN = list)))
}
data %>% select(2:ncol(data)) %>% colnames() %>% findcombo()

modelframe2 <- tibble(combos) #puts list as a column in a tibble

#dependent variable is labeled as dependent, function below creates dataframes with omitted NAs to be used for lm.fit 
modelframe2 <- modelframe2 %>% 
mutate(indep = map(combos, function(x){data %>% select(dependent, one_of(x)) %>% 
na.omit()} ))

#reg performs lm.fit on the matrices produced by the function above and generates a table of coefficients
reg <- function(mat){
return((lm.fit(cbind(1,as.matrix(mat[,2:ncol(mat)])), mat[,1]))$coefficients)
}

#applies reg across each possible combination of variables
modelframe2 <- modelframe2 %>% mutate(models = map(indep, reg))
```

Comment: Predictions can easily be calculated by matrix multiplication of a design matrix with the coefficients. Matrix multiplication is fast and can be made even faster by linking R to an optimized BLAS.

Comment: However, there is probably a better approach than fitting millions of models.